# How to gracefully end test client

Tags: java, cumulocity

I have a simple cumulocity test client. The code runs fine but the jvm does not stop when the code finishes.
Some threads are still running: MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.

How to gracefully shutdown the open connections allocated by:

```
InventoryApi inventory = platform.getInventoryApi() ?
```

_

```
...
platform = new PlatformImpl(App.C8Y_URL, new CumulocityCredentials(App.C8Y_USER, App.C8Y_PWD));
InventoryApi inventory = platform.getInventoryApi();

GId testId = new GId("123456");
ManagedObjectRepresentation testDevice = inventory.get(testId);
MeasurementApi mApi = platform.getMeasurementApi();

MeasurementRepresentation measurement = new MeasurementRepresentation();
measurement.setType("c8y_SampleRate");
measurement.setSource(testDevice);

DateTime time = new DateTime();
System.out.println("time " + time.toString());
measurement.setDateTime(time);
Map<String, Object> flowRateFragment = App.createFlowRateFragment(new BigDecimal(20.5));
measurement.set(flowRateFragment, "c8y_SampleRate");

MeasurementRepresentation measurementCreation = mApi.create(measurement);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To gracefully shutdown your Cumulocity client call `platform.close()`.

Comment: This results in an exception  `Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at com.cumulocity.sdk.client.buffering.MemoryBasedPersistentProvider.poll(MemoryBasedPersistentProvider.java:43)
 at com.cumulocity.sdk.client.buffering.BufferProcessor$1.run(BufferProcessor.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)`

Answer (score 0):

NO you cannot exit after the code finished. Cumulocity agent is made to run continuously so, they won't stop the thread. 
If you want out exit then you have use

`System.exit(0); //Change the status code accordingly`.